# Como calcular o r squared (r^2) com os exemplos de teste?

Tags: matlab, regressão

Eu parti os meus dados num conjunto para treino e outro para teste. Gostaria de saber se posso calcular o valor de r^2 para o conjunto de exemplos de teste. Eu criei dois modelos: um modelo com a SVR e outro com LinearModel (função do matlab). Agora queria comparar o RMSE (que já tenho) e o valor do coeficiente de determinação (r^2) com base nos dados de teste.

No fundo o que quero saber é se isto está correcto (para o caso das Random Forest mas a ideia também aplicada a outros modelos):

```
model = TreeBagger(100, Xtrain, Ytrain,'Method','regression');
pred = model.predict(Xtest);

Ymean = mean(Ytest);
SSt = sum((Ytest-Ymean).^2);
SSr = sum((Ytest-pred).^2);

r2 = 1-(SSr/SSt);
```

A parte estranha é que com isto obtenho RMSE = 9.29 (o que é bastante bom para o problema em questão) e um r^2 = -0.03. Isto não é contraditório?

Se este procedimento estiver certo, qual a interpretação destes resultados?

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; esta conversa foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25111/discussion-on-question-by-user25847-como-calcular-o-r-squared-r2-com-os-exemp)

Comment: Não posso escrever no chat dado que não tenho 20 pontos de reputação. Esse resultado não é o melhor ...

Comment: Bom, pronto, você já tem 20 pontos agora :)

Comment: @bfavaretto obrigado, não tinha consegui transferir